# How to get list of params in actions on google java library?

Tags: java, actions-on-google

As in the topic, how can I receive a list of params in my intent function in Java actions library? Earlier I wrote some action in JavaScript. There was an option to add an array of some kind as intent function param and receive user spoken elements in this array.

Example in Java script:

```
function askForProductsIntentHandler(conv, {products}) {}
```

How to achieve the same in java library?

Answer (score 2):

In Java, you aren't able to destructure parameters like in JavaScript, but you can access parameters in a similar way from the request.

You can see it in the [Facts about Google sample](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-facts-about-google-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/FactsAboutGoogle.java#L127):

```
private ActionResponse fact(ActionRequest request) {
    String selectedCategory = ((String) request.getParameter("category"));
    // ...
}
```